# Karmaunit-testing: Cannot read property 'eventType' of undefined thrown

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Setting up the basics in unit-testing with Karma (Angular 7) en stumbling upon .

`<testcase name="HeaderComponent should create" time="0.4" classname="HeaderComponent">
<failure type=""> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventType' of undefined thrown`

This particular property exists on `queryObject` which is used bij my Akita State Manager, however, not in HeaderComponent. There also isnt any reference to Akita Store nor to queryObject or what so ever in HeaderComponent.

How can this be an issue though?

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  menuHidden = true;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private i18nService: I18nService,
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleMenu() {
    this.menuHidden = !this.menuHidden;
  }

  setLanguage(language: string) {
    this.i18nService.language = language;
  }

  logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']));
  }

  get currentLanguage(): string {
    return this.i18nService.language;
  }

  get languages(): string[] {
    return this.i18nService.supportedLanguages;
  }

  get username(): string | null {
    const credentials = this.authenticationService.credentials;
    return credentials ? credentials.username : null;
  }
}
```

spec:

```
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, NgbModule, TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService }, I18nService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

MockAuthenticationService

```
export class MockAuthenticationService {
  credentials: Credentials | null = {
    username: 'test',
    token: '123'
  };

  login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {
    return of({
      username: context.username,
      token: '123456'
    });
  }

  logout(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.credentials = null;
    return of(true);
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.credentials;
  }

  isAuthenticatedAdmin(): boolean {
    return true; // this.genericStateModel.isAdmin;
  }
}
```

template

```
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" translate>APP_NAME</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-controls="navbar-menu"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="toggleMenu()" [attr.aria-expanded]="!menuHidden">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse float-xs-none" [ngbCollapse]="menuHidden">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/herd" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <span translate>herd</span>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="authenticationService.isAuthenticated() && authenticationService.isAuthenticatedAdmin()" class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/stock" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i>
            <span translate>stock</span>
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="authenticationService.isAuthenticated() && authenticationService.isAuthenticatedAdmin()" class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/orders" routerLinkActive="active">
            <i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>
            <span translate>orders</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <div class="nav-item" ngbDropdown placement="bottom-right">
            <a id="user-dropdown" class="nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle>
              <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
            </a>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="user-dropdown">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                <span translate>logged in as</span> <b>{{username}}</b></h6>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()" translate>logout</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Could you please show template of component?

Comment: And `MockAuthenticationService`, please